# How do I get all comment types to display in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, comments

I've recently changed my blog's theme and it apparently doesn't display all comment types, so I'm left with a lot of posts that say they have X comments, but none of them actually show up on the page.

This is the code for displaying comments from my theme's comments.php file:

```
<?php wp_list_comments('callback=infinity_comments'); ?>
```

From what I understand, I have to somehow include this:

```
( array( 'type' => 'all' ) )
```

Problem is I can't really figure out how to do it. I'm not a developer so my knowledge is pretty limited.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

**===== Update =====**

@zipkundan That seems to work, but it's like the comments don't have any CSS rules and they're all messed up, so now there's that. (pic: https://i.imgur.com/u2ibqUA.png)

Here's the "infinity_comments" function:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'infinity_comments' ) ) {

function infinity_comments ( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
$_GLOBAL['comment'] = $comment;

if(get_comment_type() == 'pingback' || get_comment_type() == 'trackback' ) : ?>

<li class="pingback" id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
    <article <?php comment_class('entry-comments'); ?> >
        <div class="comment-content">
            <h3 class="comment-author">
                <?php esc_html_e( 'Pingback:', 'flexblog' ); ?>
            </h3>   
            <span class="comment-date" >
            <a href=" <?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link() ); ?> " class="comment-date" >
                <?php
                comment_date( get_option('date_format') );
                esc_html_e( '&nbsp;at&nbsp;', 'flexblog' );
                comment_time( get_option('time_format') );
                ?>
            </a>
            <?php
                echo edit_comment_link( esc_html__('&nbsp;[Edit]', 'flexblog' ) );
            ?>
            </span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="comment-text">          
            <?php comment_author_link(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</li>

<?php elseif (get_comment_type() == 'comment') : ?>

    <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">

        <article <?php comment_class('entry-comments'); ?> >                    
            <figure class="comment-avatar">
                <?php 
                    $avatar_size = 60;
                    if( $comment->comment_parent != 0 ) {
                        $avatar_size = 55;
                    }
                    echo get_avatar( $comment, $avatar_size );
                ?>
            </figure>
            <div class="comment-content">
            <h3 class="comment-author">
                <?php comment_author_link(); ?>
            </h3>
            <span class="comment-date" >
            <a href=" <?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link() ); ?> ">
                <?php
                comment_date( get_option('date_format') );
                esc_html_e( '&nbsp;at&nbsp;', 'flexblog' );
                comment_time( get_option('time_format') );
                ?>
            </a>
            <?php
                echo edit_comment_link( esc_html__('&nbsp;[Edit]', 'flexblog' ) );
            ?>
            </span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="comment-text">
            <?php if($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
            <p class="awaiting-moderation"><?php esc_html_e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'flexblog'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php comment_text(); ?>
            </div>
            </div>
            <span class="reply">
                <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array( 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']) ) ); ?>
            </span> 
        </article>                          
<?php endif;
}
}
```

I tried using your code in comments.php and replacing "comment" with "all" in this line in functions.php:

```
    <?php elseif (get_comment_type() == 'comment') : ?>
```

but nothing changed. The comments display, but they're not following any CSS rules.

Any idea how to fix that?

Thank you!

**===== Update 2 =====**

In the functions.php code I mentioned above, there's this:

```
<?php elseif (get_comment_type() == 'comment') : ?>
```

If I replace "comment" with "social-twitter" or "social-facebook" (the two types of comments that currently don't appear, it works, they appear just fine. This, however, makes all other comment types not appear. So the solution seems pretty simple, I just need to mention "comment", "social-twitter", and "social-facebook" in that line of code so all currently existing comment types appear. The question I have now is how exactly should I format the list? I just tried writing *'comment', 'social-facebook', 'social-twitter',* but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The code of the "infinity_comments" function you have posted is missing "</li>", which closing tag of "<li>". Try adding "</li>" (with out quotes) at the end of the function just after "</article>" and before "<?php endif;". I hope that will at least fix the formatting. Please try and let us know.

Comment: Unfortunately closing that <li> didn't do anything. I feel like the code in functions.php should be alright as it is, as regular comments show up just fine on the blog, it's only after replacing the code in comments.php with the one you suggested that the CSS gets messed up (for all comments, not just the ones that show up after using the code). Like I said, my knowledge is pretty limited, but that's just how it looks to me. What do you think?

Comment: Can you post url of your blog? (as a comment)

Comment: Sure, here's an article with one comment that doesn't show up: https://blog.ovidiuav.com/2015/11/03/cum-ma-simt-ca-client-ing/

Just as an FYI, the comments that aren't showing up were imported some time ago from Facebook & Twitter using the "Social" plugin by Mailchimp, and the plugin used different comment types for them.

Comment: Hey @zipkundan, please see my latest update, I've made some progress.

Comment: Hi @ovidiuav, great find. Please see the update in my answer. Please try that and let me know how that works.

Comment: That did the trick, it all works perfectly now. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned you have following line in your comments.php file.

```
<?php wp_list_comments('callback=infinity_comments'); ?>
```

Update/change it to following.

```
<?php
     $arg = array(
         'callback'=>'infinity_comments',
         'type'=>'all'
     );
     wp_list_comments(); 
?>
```

If this does not solve your problem, then the problem lies within the custom function "infinity_comments" in your new theme. In that find that function in you new theme and post that function's code for examination.

Hope this helps.

Update after "Update 2" in question.

In that case you can try and update the elseif as follows.

```
<?php elseif (get_comment_type() == 'comment' || get_comment_type() == 'social-twitter' || get_comment_type() == 'social-facebook') : ?>
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: My answer was too long for posting as a comment so I had to post it as an answer and I don't know if that notifies you. Please see below.

Comment: @ovidiuav I would suggest, instead of posting your response as answer you should update your question with you response. That way it will be easier for other readers to follow the updates. You can just edit your question and post your response below original content.

Comment: I have updated your original question with your response. So, you can delete the one you wrote as answer.